# Walks and paths in a graph

Tags: graph-theory, network

How can we prove the following?

In a graph, if there is a *k*-length walk between two nodes, then there exists a path between those nodes of length *p ≤ k*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply take the vertices along the walk; if you come to the same vertex twice, erase everything that was in between.