# Rigorously prove that a u-v walk implies a u-v path of equal or lesser length .

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to prove the following as an unofficial exercise for a course I'm in: [Walks and paths in a graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85271/walks-and-paths-in-a-graph)

Prove: For any graph if there is a k-length walk between two nodes, then there exists a path between those nodes of length p ≤ k.

I've seen the short proofs by contradiction online, and I understand the intuition. However my professor suggested I supply a proof by induction, so I was hoping to present my proof / proof sketch receive some feedback.

Consider an arbitrary network G = (N,g) such that G is connected.

case 1: the walk contains no cycles, this immediately implies that there exists at least one path (i.e. the walk with no cycle) by definition of a path , and we're done.

case 2: There exists at least one cycle of arbitrary length n.

basis step: there exists a u-v walk containing one cycle of arbitrary length n. Let W1 be the path from nodes u to c, W2 = the n nodes involved in the cycle, and W3 = nodes c+1 through v. We simply eliminate the cycle, i.e. follow the link from path W1 to W3 , call this W1W3 which is less than W as required.

induction step: show that a u-v walk containing m cycles is shorter than a walk containing m+1 cycles, ceteris paribus. This is largely the same logic as above, and so I omit it here.

Am I on the right track? I came to formal mathematics rather later in life, through advanced study in Econ, so take pity.

Thanks!

Comment: Here's a further hint without trying to give the whole thing away. Rather than induct on the number of cycles, I would use the well ordering principle (equivalent to induction but cleaner in this case) and consider the lengths of all possible walks from u to v.

Comment: @gabe But I think that then you run into exactly the proof the OP tries to avoid: how do you prove that the shortest walk is a path WITHOUT using contradiction?

Comment: The idea looks OK to me, since you start at the case $0$ cycles, you should consider this as the base case, there is no need to worry about the case with $1$ cycle. And there is no need to worry about the length of the cycle, this just introduces an extra variable, which is not needed. You never used $n$ in your proof. And as you said, when you prove $P(1)$, you are really proving $P(0)\rightarrow P(1)$, that's why the inductive step is the same...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys!

@gabe so the idea then would be to consider the entire set of possible walks b/ u and v, choose the walk(s) with the minimum path length, then show by contradiction that it contains no cycles?

Comment: @N.S. Thanks! For some reason I was thinking of the 0 case as special. The idea with the n sized cycle was to use universal generalization to make it clear that we can say this about any sized cycle. Since I'm so new to graph theory, I feel like I'm just reverting to explaining intuition in my proof, rather than carrying the argument forward.